# Evitar aspas duplas em arquivo CSV exportado com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

É possível evitar que o arquivo `CSV` venha com `aspas duplas` em campos string, estou usando o script abaixo, mas o campo `nome` está vindo entre `aspas duplas`, como posso evitar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "simrede"); 
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Falha ao fazer conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // Set utf8
      mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
      $connect->set_charset('utf8');
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Gabaritos_OMR_Alunos-Simrede.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('ROLLNO', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'EMAILID', 'PHONENO'),';');  
      $query = 'SELECT ROLLNO, nome, concat(".",nivel,"ano"), concat(id,"@gmail.com"), siem_id from cs_gabarito';  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row,";");  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

> **Edit**
>   A resposta do Júlio Neto usando `fwrite` e `implode` serviu, bastou adicionar quebra de linha no último campo da consulta pra evitar junção do último campo com o
>   primeiro de cada linha, como segue:

```
..., concat(siem_id,"\n") from cs_gabarito';
```

Comment: Poderia editar a questão e colocar um exemplo de saída CSV?

Comment: sim sim, um momento

Comment: @fernandosavio adicionei imagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem duas soluções, uma é passar uma string vazia no quarto argumento da função fputcsv:

```
fputcsv($output, $row, ";", "");
```

Ou reescrever a linha que grava no arquivo os dados, usando o implode pra juntar os registros:

```
fwrite($output, implode(";", $row));
```

Tenta um dos dois e diz se funciona.

Comment: Testando aqui, ja já passo o resultado

Comment: Usei a função `fwrite` com `implode`, mas ele juntava tudo, tratando o último campo e o primeiro como sendo um só, então adicionei um `concat` e `\n` no último campo na consulta  pra quebrar a linha depois do último campo e resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

A função [`fputcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) sempre coloca um caracter de *enclosure* (que por padrão é `"` - aspa dupla) o campo sendo tratado tem espaços. Se o campo já contém um valor igual ao *enclosure* ele duplica. Neste caso: `sou um "campo" com aspas` viraria `"sou um ""campo"" com aspas"`.

Teoricamente nada disso importa muito se você usar [`fgetcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), pois a função trata disso automaticamente.

Se você for implementar algo na mão, é necessário lembrar sempre de escapar os caracteres da string que entram em conflito com os que você estiver usando como separador.

[Aqui tem um exemplo](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/ForkedWearyLocks) mostrando os comportamentos da função.

Answer (score -2):

// Pegando a última chave do array
$last_key = array_key_last($header);

```
    // Pegando o nome da última chave do array
    $name_last_key = $header[$last_key];

    // Adicionando uma quebra de linha no valor da última chave do array
    $header[$last_key] = $header[$last_key]."\n";

    // Escrever no arquivo o array transformado em string separado por ";"
    fwrite($file, implode(";", $header));
```